# Azure Powershell - get owner emails for list of SPNs and EAs

Tags: azure, powershell, owner

I was given a long list of ObjectIds. Unfortunately these ObjectIds are for both Enterprise Applications and Service Principals.

So I load the CSV file and for each ObjectId I need to

1. Determine ObjectType (EA or SPN)
2. Get the Object's DisplayName
3. Get Object's owners emails (comma separated)

The result should be CSV showing columns: ObjectId, ObjectType, DisplayName, Owners.

```
$csv = Import-Csv c:\data\cso-list.csv
$DisplayName=@()

foreach ($ObjectId in $csv) {
    
        $DisplayName += (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $ObjectId.ID | Select-Object ObjectType, DisplayName, ObjectId)
        
        Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner -ObjectId $ObjectId.ID | Select Mail

        $DisplayName += Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner -ObjectId $ObjectId.ID | Select Mail
}

$DisplayName | Export-Csv c:\data\cso-list-done.csv
```

I can do it either for EA or SPN but not for both. And even when using -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue I still get an error when for example ObjectId is for EA but query is for ServicePrincipal, and vice versa.

I also tried following but it did not help.

```
if (!(Get-AzADApplication -ObjectId $ObjectId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{
  Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $ObjectId | select DisplayName
  Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner -ObjectId $ObjectId | Select Mail
}

if (!(Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $ObjectId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{
  Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $ObjectId | Select DisplayName
  Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $ObjectId | Select Mail
}
```

Can you please advise how to handle this? I'm sure there's an easy solution but I did not find it even after several hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that, **Enterprise applications** tab contains list of service principals. I believe your CSV file has object IDs of App registrations and service principals from Enterprise applications.

To **determine** the **`ObjectType`** whether it's service principal or application, you can run below PowerShell command:

```
Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectId 82433924-95cf-4609-xxxxxx | fl
```

**Response:**

[image]

I have two app registrations named **`AppReg01`** and **`AppReg02`** with Sridevi as **Owner** :

[image]

In Enterprise applications tab, I have two **service principals** named **`EntApp01`** and **`EntApp02`** with Venkat as **Owner**:

[image]

To export **required details** to CSV file, I ran below PowerShell script and got **response** like this:

```
$results = @()

$objectIds = Import-Csv -Path "C:\test\csvs\file.csv" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID

foreach ($objectId in $objectIds) {
    $object = Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectId $objectId

    if ($object.ObjectType -eq "Application") {
        $owner = Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $objectId
    }
    elseif ($object.ObjectType -eq "ServicePrincipal") {
        $owner = Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner -ObjectId $objectId
    }
    else {
        $owner = $null
    }

    $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
        ObjectId            = $object.ObjectId
        ObjectType          = $object.ObjectType
        DisplayName         = $object.DisplayName
        OwnerDisplayName    = if ($owner) { $owner.DisplayName } else { $null }
        OwnerEmailAddress   = if ($owner) { $owner.mail } else { $null }
    }

    $results += $result
    Write-Output "$($result.ObjectType): $($result.DisplayName)"
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\test\csvs\srioutput.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the CSV file, it has **required details** with columns: ObjectId, ObjectType, DisplayName, OwnerDisplayName, **OwnerEmailAddress** like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for such a great explanation and example with screenshots!
However for most of the items in OwnerDisplayName and OwnerEmailAddress
 columns in CSV I'm getting "System.Object[]" instead of comma separated data.
Usually there are multiple owners.

Comment: I added  -join ', ' to both and it does what I needed. Thanks a lot again!